# Google Chrome doesn't run anymore

Tags: windows, google-chrome

When I click on it, the cursor juts blinks for a second and nothing happens. Nothing Google related is found in task manager either. CPU and Memory usage levels are normal. Just started happening yesterday

- Tried reinstalling
- System restore's turned off (I never use it and it
  takes up space)

Comment: Or a System Restore?

Comment: Tried reinstalling

Comment: System restore's off

Comment: Btw you need to @ mention users to have them receive notifications. /cc @KCotreau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. Fixed it using `cmd`

`"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\<Chrome version>\Installer\setup.exe" --rename-chrome-exe`